# Pris par / d' un élan de frénésie

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Pris **par** un élan de frénésie, A se lève.
>
> Pris **d**'un élan de frénésie, A se lève.

Les deux phrases sont correctes, n'est-ce pas ? Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre elles ?

Answer (score 2):

Les deux phrases sont correctes mais je privilégierais la deuxième.

Sans que la distinction soit toujours franche, ***pris par*** me semble plus indiqué quand il s'agit de quelque chose d'extérieur (ex: *pris par surprise*, *pris par la foule*, *pris par l'enthousiasme*) alors que ***pris de*** indique plus une source interne (*pris de fièvre, pris de convulsions, pris de panique*).

On peut aussi se passer de *pris* et écrire :

> Dans un élan de frénésie, A se lève.