# Inonder par / de questions

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

J'ai écrit sur le chat :

> Peut-être que j'aurais dû poser cette question sur le site ?... Je ne
> voulais pas l'inonder par mes questions sur les articles.

Est-ce qu'il s'agit de la même logique expliquée dans ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46832/pris-par-d-un-%C3%A9lan-de-fr%C3%A9n%C3%A9sie) ? Si c'est le cas, "par" convient mieux, à mon avis.

Answer (score 2):

Au sens figuré, la forme standard est *inonder de quelque chose*, parfois *inonder avec quelque chose*. Ces prépositions sont assez figées. Tu peux quand même écrire *inonder par mes questions* et on comprendra ce que tu veux dire mais *inonder* y a normalement son sens propre (0 hits dans Google books, 2 pour *inondé par des questions*).

Tu aurais pu aussi utiliser l'expression équivalente: *submerger de questions* qui accepte plus facilement la variante *submerger par des questions*, même si elle reste quand même bien plus rare.

Comment: Merci. Il y a des exemples contenant "par" dans Antidote : _inondée par la pluie_, _inondé par la lumière_, _inondé par une vague_, _inondé par les larmes_. Cependant, ils ne sont pas tous au sens propre. _Depuis la longue et véhémente effusion à son père, Jean se les est rappelés encore, inondé **par une vague semblable de repos et de douceur**._ Hector Bernier, _Ce que disait la flamme_. Mais oui, je n'en ai trouvé qu'un.